# Linear combinations of four-dimensional vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $v_1  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ $v_2  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ $v_3  =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ $v_4  =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ $\mathbb{R}^4$ vectors.

*Show that every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times1}$  can be written as vectors $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ linear combination.*

My attempt:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|l}
1 & 0 & 0 & 2  &v_1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0  & v_2\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0  &v_3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1  &v_4\\
\end{array}
\right]$

Where do I go from here? Every input is appreciated.

Comment: What do you think that matrix means? The last column is a column of 16 numbers isn't it?

Comment: Note:  $\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&2\\1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\end{vmatrix}=-1\ne0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\det A=-1\ne 0$, given any vector $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$, we solve the linear system $AX=B$ with
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);\;X=\left(
x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4
\right)$$
and thank to Cramer's theorem we get as unique solution  the components $X$ of $B$ in the base $\left(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&2\\1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}0&0&2\\1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{vmatrix}=1+\begin{vmatrix}0&2\\1&1\end{vmatrix}=-1\ne0$,

so the four vectors are linearly independent, so they span $\mathbb R^4$,

so any vector in $\mathbb R^4$ can be expressed as a linear combination of them.